# Enable and Disable the buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to enable and disable the buttons using jQuery or Javascript.

The real scenario is: if I click the start button it goes to the php table column if the status is in running state the start button gets disabled same if the status is in stopped state the start button need to enable.

Comment: please post your effort (hint: code).

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('#button-id').attr('disabled', true);
jQuery('#button-id').attr('disabled', false);
```

You just needs to change the disabled attribute value

Answer (score 1):

Please use Ajax by JQuery.

```
$('#btn').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault()
    let btn = $(this)
    btn_disable(btn)

    $.ajax({
        url: 'your_url',
        method: 'your_method',
        data: {your_data}, //if you haven't data please type {}

        success: function (response) {
            btn_enable(btn)
        },

        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            btn_enable(btn)
        },

        complete: function (response) {
            btn_enable(btn)
        }

    })
})

function btn_disable(btn) {
    btn.attr('disabled', 'disabled')
    btn.addClass('disabled')
}

function btn_enable(btn) {
    btn.removeAttr('disabled')
    btn.removeClass('disabled')
}
```

Here you can read more about Ajax : 
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below sample. If the API response is true then the button gets disabled and if it's false then it gets enabled

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "ur_Api, success: function(result){
    if(result === true){
      $("#btn_status").attr('disabled', true);
      }
      else {
        $("#btn_status").attr('disabled', false);
    }});
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button id="btn_status">Status</button>

</body>
</html>
```